# Change gradient widths

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

The code below creates diagonal lines by using CSS gradient. But how can I make the coloured line thinner about 2px, and the white space in-between larger about 7px?

```
body {
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #fff), color-stop(0.25, #fff), color-stop(0.25, #9CC), color-stop(0.5, #9CC), color-stop(0.5, #fff), color-stop(0.75, #fff), color-stop(0.75, #9CC));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 25%, #9CC 25%, #9CCb 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 75%, #9CC 75%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 25%, #9CC 25%, #9CC 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 75%, #9cc 75%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 25%, #bbb 25%, #bbb 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 75%, #bbb 75%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 25%, #9CC 25%, #9CC 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 75%, #9CC 75%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#9CC',GradientType=0 ); / IE6-8 */
background-image: linear-gradient(right bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 25%, #9CC 25%, #9CC 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 75%, #9CC 75%);
background-size: 5px 5px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using js rotate plugins like jqueryrotate? You could create much simpler elements like hr or div and then rotate them. Just a suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it by changing the percents of the gradient to smaller or larger values, `#fff` = white so the range should be larger. `#9CC` is the blue color, its range should be smaller.

```
body {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #fff), color-stop(0.35, #fff), color-stop(0.35, #9CC), color-stop(0.5, #9CC), color-stop(0.5, #fff), color-stop(0.85, #fff), color-stop(0.85, #9CC));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 35%, #9CC 35%, #9CCb 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 85%, #9CC 85%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 35%, #9CC 35%, #9CC 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 85%, #9cc 85%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 35%, #bbb 35%, #bbb 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 85%, #bbb 85%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 35%, #9CC 35%, #9CC 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 85%, #9CC 85%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#9CC', GradientType=0);
    / IE6-8 */ background-image: linear-gradient(right bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 35%, #9CC 35%, #9CC 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 85%, #9CC 85%);
    background-size: 5px 5px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LqA3U/)

I changed the `25%` to `35%` and `75%` to `80%` correspondingly which lessened the range and therefore width of the blue lines and increased the range and therefore the width of the white lines

To change them yourself you may want to use a [find and replace tool](http://textmechanic.com/Find-and-Replace-Text.html)